# How can I tell if a control is disabled because of a parent container?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a bug in a Windows Forms app that I have to fix.  There is a groupbox that contains some controls (a few labels, some DevXPress "SpinEdit"s, and some checkboxes).  The groupbox is disabled when the form is instantiated, which causes the controls inside to be disabled.  In certain cases, the user can press a toolbar button to enable those controls.  What I am seeing is that when I enable the groupbox, the controls inside don't re-enable.  If I loop through and enable them manually, the labels and checkboxes "work," but the SpinEdit's don't.  The up/down buttons work, but the text entry area is stubbornly disabled or readonly or something.  Inspecting the SpinEdit shows that everything *should* be fine for editing.

Is there any way to check to see if there is some container control that's keeping these controls disabled?

Comment: I suspect this to be a DX bug, Winforms doesn't exhibit such behavior, i.e. when container is enabled all the controls inside are restored - restored as in, returned to the state prior to disabling the container. A̶l̶s̶o̶,̶ ̶c̶h̶i̶l̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶'̶s̶ ̶E̶n̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶p̶e̶r̶t̶y̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶a̶i̶n̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶.̶ I take that back, Enabled of child controls is affected.

Comment: FWIW, It did this when they were "NumericUpDown" controls, too.